# Variable in HTML getting wiped?

Tags: python, html, post, flask

I have created a session variable through the line `session["Appointments"] = []` earlier on.

In another separate function, this is the `Python` code. The print function returns a number that indicates a non-empty list.

```
@app.route("/Dashboard.html", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def Dashboard():

    if request.method == "POST":
        session["Appointments"].append(stuff)
        print("Available appointments:", len(session["Appointments"]))
    return render_template("Dashboard.html")
```

Below is part of the `HTML` file. The desired outcome is a number that is not zero, but when running it is zero, representing an empty list.

```
{{ session["Appointments"]|length }}
```

I need to know why this is the case. Thank you ever so much in advance.

Comment: `session["CurrentDateAppointments"]` and `session["Appointments"]` are different, aren't they?

Comment: Oops no, they're supposed to be the same - let me edit that.